# Why does Apache Commons CSVParser.getHeaderMap() always return null?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

When reading the following TSV snippet with Apache Commons CSV:

```
Name    DOB SIN Address, contact information
"Patience Middleton"    "18-4-87"   720463771   "varius Cras sem aliquam taciti fames hendrerit tempor"
```

This is my code:

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.newFormat('\t').withQuote('"');
CSVParser parsed = CSVParser.parse(csvData, format);
List<CSVRecord> record = parsed.getRecords();
System.out.println(parsed.getHeaderMap().toString());
```

However I always get a `NullPointerException` stating that `parsed.getHeaderMap() == null`.

According to the API (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html), the method may return a copy of the header map that iterates in column order.

Is there something wrong in my code or CSV file? Is the library failing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default `CSVParser` assumes that there is no header line and parses the first line as regular data. You need to tell it explicitly that you want the first line of your CSV file to be interpreted as a header by calling [`withHeader()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withHeader-java.lang.String...-) on `CSVFormat`:

```
CSVParser parsed = CSVParser.parse(csvData, 
   CSVFormat.newFormat('\t').withQuote('"').withHeader());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I saw may parameters in withHeader() function and naively thought they are only used to manually set headers.